# What fonts are out there that are designed like monospaced fonts, but aren't completely monospaced?

Tags: typography, monospace

What options are out there for fonts that are designed similarly to monospaced fonts, but are not 100% monospaced?  They should have large, clear punctuation marks, wide spaces, and most characters should be the same width, though certain characters may be larger or smaller.  Some people might like to program with such a font.  In my case it is for use in headings of programming-centric blog posts.

I know of two such free font families that I can give as examples:  [Input](https://input.fontbureau.com/preview), and [iA Writer](https://ia.net/topics/in-search-of-the-perfect-writing-font).  What else is out there?

Comment: Programmers tend to want monospaced fonts, FYI.

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a font for programming.  I am looking for fonts that looks like programming fonts, but are more comfortable for reading normal text -- the m is not squished, for example.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Not sure I understand this question or the reasoning behind it. Programmers use monospace fonts so that all the letters/symbols and numbers line up on different rows. So if you want to simulate that look, best to go for an actual monospace font.  If the font has characters of variable width, they will not line up, defeating the entire purpose, because it will no longer look like a programming font.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I'm a programmer and I always use a monospaced font for writing code. Fonts like the ones listed still look like programming fonts, even though they don't align vertically perfectly (which doesn't matter for most non-programming use cases anyway). The links I provided give a lot of the reasoning behind these type of fonts. You can read more there if you like. Note that they are closer to a monospaced font than to a traditional proportional font. I'm just trying to find out if there are more of them than the two that I have already found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a much larger list here by searching Google for 'proportional typewriter fonts':

https://www.isoglosse.de/2018/02/proportionally-spaced-typefaces-with-a-monospaced-appearance/

It contains a list of quite of few more of these pseudo-mono fonts.

Since it seems that my question was not well-understood, let me also give some other info about the reasoning behind using these fonts.  Many of them were actually designed for programming use.  Here's the case Input makes for programming with a proportional font, from https://input.fontbureau.com/info/:

> In addition to a monospaced version, Input offers
>   proportionally-spaced Sans and Serif font families specifically
>   designed for code and data. Unlike most proportional designs, these
>   fonts adopt the helpful attributes of a monospaced design — generous
>   spacing, large punctuation, easily distinguishable characters — while
>   allowing each character to take up the space that it needs.
>
> The proportional styles provide a more comfortable alternative to the
>   monospaced fonts used for everything from text composition to
>   correspondence to code. The capitals get wider so they can feel at
>   home with the lowercase. The Bold weight gets wider so it can feel at
>   home with the Regular. The Condensed styles can work together
>   alongside the Normal width, and the Serif can provide an alternative
>   texture to the Sans.
>
> In code, indentation is an important (and sometimes semantically
>   significant) indicator of hierarchy and scope. When using a
>   proportional font, the only indentation that matters is the
>   indentation at the beginning of the line.

And I found one other font that didn't make the list in that block post: [ETC Trispace][1], which is based on League Mono.

> MOST glyphs in ETC Trispace share the same width but we wanted to make
>   the narrowest forms take up slightly less space (i, l, j, space,
>   quotes, and a few others) and the widest forms take up slightly more
>   space (M, m, W, w, Æ, æ, Œ, œ, @, and &). We did this to retain the
>   feel of a monospace font but on a slightly more readable level. We
>   also didn’t invent this concept, but if it is new to you, then great!

I do prefer programming with a true monospace font, but whether you are looking for it for programming or something else, there are plenty of reasons somebody might want to use a pseudo-mono font.  That's why I asked the question, and so I was surprised by all the "just use a monospaced font" comments.  In any case, if you are looking for a font that tries to strike a balance between the aesthetics and properties of monospaced and proportional fonts, I hope this answer finds you!

Comment: That's a very interesting article you found.  However, it would be a much better answer if you could explain briefly the main points of the article rather than relying upon a link only, since links are prone to rot.  If you edit it, I will upvote it. Then you could accept your own answer as best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will do that when I have some time, but not likely today.